# Python Error "Float"

Tags: python

I am getting TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'. Here is my code:

```
# Define x[i][j] for Gurobi
for i in S:
    for j in D:
        decvarx[i][j] = m.addVar(lb = 0, obj=c[i][j]*u[i], vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="x.%d.%d" % (i,j))
```

I think there is a problem with u[i] but I'm not really sure. Here is the code for u[i]:

```
# u is an array of supply values (indexed on processing facility numbers).

u = []
for i in range(0,max(S)+1):
    u.append([])                            # Add an empty spot for u[i]
for row in range(0,len(FAC_data)):
    i = int(FAC_data[row][0])               # This is the processing facility number
    u[i] = 1000*FAC_data[row][2]            # This is the supply for this processing facility
```

Thank you for any help you can provide!!!!

Comment: I think the problem is with `c`, not `u`. if `c[i][j]` is a list or something, you can't multiply it by a float.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue is that you are attempting to create a list of ints where

```
u = [123,546,887,890]
```

and it is indexed on your different facility numbers.

however, your loop -

```
for i in range(0,max(S)+1):
    u.append([])                            # Add an empty spot for u[i]
```

actually creates this:

```
u = [[],[],[],[]]
```

which is a list of lists. therefore, when you try to multiply what you think is an integer, you are actually trying to multiply a single-element list.  Since lists are not arrays, you have an alternative.  Lists, unlike arrays, are dynamic.  So, you can just append the values directly into the list.  Now, if your facility numbers do not happen to start with zero, I recommend using a dictionary instead.

```
u = {}

for row in range(0,len(FAC_data)):
    key = int(FAC_data[row][0]) 
    data = 1000*FAC_data[row][2]
    u[key] = data
```

to retrieve the data for later use, just use:

```
needed_data = u[facility_id]
```

dictionaries seem intimidating at first, but they are the fastest way to retrieve information.